# Create new list of substrings from list of strings

Tags: python, list, substring

Is there an easy way in python of creating a list of substrings from a list of strings?

Example:

original list: `['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop']`

list of substrings: `['bc','fg','jk','no']`

I know this could be achieved with a simple loop but is there an easier way in python (Maybe a one-liner)?

Comment: there can be many substrings . you have shown only from index [1-2]..
Do you have a specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `slicing` and `list comprehension`:

```
>>> lis = ['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop']
>>> [ x[1:3] for x in lis]
['bc', 'fg', 'jk', 'no']
```

Slicing:

```
>>> s = 'abcd'
>>> s[1:3]      #return sub-string from 1 to 2th index (3 in not inclusive)
'bc'
```

Comment: Dammit, just a bit quicker than me! :)

Comment: thanks, it works :) (For some reason I can't accept your answer till in 11minutes)

Answer (score 1):

With a mix of slicing and list comprehensions you can do it like this

```
listy = ['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop']
[item[1:3] for item in listy]
>> ['bc', 'fg', 'jk', 'no']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one-liner [list-comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1561176), and relative positions, you can then trim the first and last character in each item.

```
>>> l = ['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop']
>>> [x[1:-1] for x in l]
['bc', 'fg', 'jk', 'no']
```

If you are doing this many times, consider using a function:

```
def trim(string, trim_left=1, trim_right=1):
    return string[trim_left:-trim_right]

def trim_list(lst, trim_left=1, trim_right=1):
    return [trim(x, trim_left, trim_right) for x in lst] 

>>> trim_list(['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop'])
['bc', 'fg', 'jk', 'no']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in one line you could try this:

```
>>> map(lambda s: s[1:-1], ['abcd','efgh','ijkl','mnop'])
```